# Is there any way to get the latest chrome version?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am writing a simple program in python and I need to get the latest release version of Chrome.
But I can not find anywhere how to get the latest version of Chrome.
Is there a way to get the latest release version of Chrome programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official link from Chrome team.
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE 
This gives the latest Chrome release version

I wrote a simple Python function getting the latest versions from the above source.

```
import requests

def get_chrome_latest_release():
    url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    return response.text

print(get_chrome_latest_release())
```

The test result is as follows.

```
78.0.3904.70
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great one, note: no need for bs4 :D

Comment: Yes, sure. Edited the answer. Thanks, Adam.

Comment: Isn't this returning the latest version of `chromedriver`, and not `chrome`?

Comment: Echoing @user453441 comment, isn't this the latest version of the driver, and not chrome browser?

Comment: I didn't find any official document stating about the relationship between Chrome version and the corresponding Chrome driver version but I believe they are almost same, at least the major version number.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax will allow you to get the latest version of chromedriver:

```
wget -q https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(wget -q -O - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE)/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer returns the latest version of the Chromedriver, rather than Chrome, here is how you can get the latest version of Chrome:

### Google's `versionhistory` API

Google provides [an API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/versionhistory/) to get information on the version history of Chrome for different platforms (Windows, Linux etc.) and channels (dev, beta, stable etc.).

The URI pattern is:

```
https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/<platform>/channels/<channel>/versions
```

To get information on the latest stable version of Chrome for Linux, for example, query:

https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/linux/channels/stable/versions

This will return a JSON object containing information on all versions for that platform and channel. In our example it would look like this:

```
{
  "versions": [
    {
      "name": "chrome/platforms/linux/channels/stable/versions/106.0.5249.119",
      "version": "106.0.5249.119"
    },
    {
      "name": "chrome/platforms/linux/channels/stable/versions/106.0.5249.103",
      "version": "106.0.5249.103"
    },
    {
      "name": "chrome/platforms/linux/channels/stable/versions/106.0.5249.91",
      "version": "106.0.5249.91"
    },
    {
      "name": "chrome/platforms/linux/channels/stable/versions/106.0.5249.61",
      "version": "106.0.5249.61"
    },
    ...
    {
      "name": "chrome/platforms/linux/channels/stable/versions/54.0.2840.71",
      "version": "54.0.2840.71"
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": ""
}
```

### Get latest Chrome version with Python

```
import json
import requests

def get_chrome_latest_release(platform: str, channel: str):
    url = f"https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/{platform}/channels/{channel}/versions"
    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    json_results = json.loads(response.text)
    return json_results['versions'][0]['version']

print(get_chrome_latest_release("linux", "stable"))
```

### Get latest Chrome version in a script

```
VERSION=$(wget -q -O - https://versionhistory.googleapis.com/v1/chrome/platforms/linux/channels/stable/versions | jq -r '.versions[0].version')
```

Note that this requires `jq` for parsing the JSON response. If it is not available in your environment you install it with `apt-get install jq` or `apk add jq`. Alternatively, use another tool for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my browser and right now the latest version is 105.0.5195.102 however visiting that URL:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE
returns this: 105.0.5195.52  which clearly is NOT the latest version.